# How to set woocommerce checkout form values to empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce plugin for a WordPress site. But when as user I checkout I can see form populated with last user's details. How to set form entries to blank in Woocommerce. Please help.
Fields are pre-populated with last user's detail. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure with your exact issue , but there might be two possible situations in your case.

1. You might me logged in with same user and then trying to
   checkout, as woo-commerce will fetch the details of currently active
   user and auto fill it during checkout.
2. Fields might get auto fill from your browser cache , try to checkout using another browser or
   by clearing cache , if its due to cache than that's not an issue at
   all, as it your browser functionality which keep the data store
   temporarily for your next usage.

Comment: Though I tried it logging off from admin but still it was somehow keeping it in cache. But now fixed. Thanks.